# How to center text and have it right aligned while keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I've been using css for a couple of years now but this issue has really perplexed me.  I want to right align some text and keep the text inline on larger screens when space is available.  When the screen size shrinks (on a mobile device) and the texts breaks to multiple lines, I need the text centered but still right aligned.

For example:

Enough space, everything on one line right aligned:

```
------------------------------------
             Total Amount: $200,000|
------------------------------------
```

On small screens, text centered on multiple lines and right aligned:

```
--------------------
      Total Amount:|
        $200,000   |
--------------------
```

My solutions always end up centered and not right aligned:

```
--------------------
   Total Amount:   |
      $200,000     |
--------------------
```

or right aligned but not centered:

```
--------------------
      Total Amount:|
           $200,000|
--------------------
```

Here's a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jmn7yLgo/) which demonstrates the issue.  The text right-aligns fine when there's enough space.  But, if you shrink the screen until the text splits to multiple lines, you'll notice the text becomes centered and no longer right aligned.

How can I get the text to be both centered and right aligned when the text splits to multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

I set the width to min-width: 160px (consider this is the text that will show). 
As for centering -  I use the margin: auto. 
And for right alignment I use… well text-align: right.

Take a look:

```
<div style="max-width: 75%; margin: auto;">
   <div style="text-align: right;">
     <span style="display: inline-block; min-width: 160px;">Total Amount Available:</span>
     <span>$200,000,000</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { div {width: 200px; }span {display: block;} }
</style>
<div>
   <div style="text-align: right;">
     <span>Total Amount Available:</span>
     <span>$200,000,000</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but when the screen size is reduce and $200,000,000 breaks to another line, it is right aligned instead of centered under "Total Amount Available:" I need the multiple lines centered but the whole block right aligned.